# Why do I get 'Error: External interaction required' when using getAccessTokenSilently in my auth0-protected React app?

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I have a problem with the auth0 silent token. I am using the auth0 actions to do a postRegister. The problem is that when I want to use any request to my API that requires authentication. It gives me error: External interaction required. and I need to log out and log back in to fix it

Hello! I have a problem with my user registry that i can’t seem to find the right way of solving, I am using an action:

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

exports.onExecutePostLogin = async (event, api) => {

  if(event.stats.logins_count <= 1){
      api.redirect.sendUserTo("http://localhost:5173/Informacion-Adicional")
  }else{
    api.redirect.sendUserTo
  }
};

exports.onContinuePostLogin = async (event, api) => {
};
```

my code for the state.
I’m just passing the part of the state. that is not all

```
 const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search)
  const state = searchParams.get('state')
  const [ continueUrl ] = useState(`https://dev-elbuensabor.us.auth0.com/continue?state=${state}`)

window.location.href = continueUrl;

//I have a fetch for the post data and it ends with a 

.finally(()=>{
       window.location.href = continueUrl;       
      });
```

The problem is that my user once is already registered. In your first login (the one that comes by default after registering) you cannot perform any action as an authenticated user. In order to perform these actions I must log out and in again.

When using useAuth0 isAuthenticated it seems that I indeed AM authenticated. The problem is when I want to perform one of my fetchs to retrieve the information

```
export default function ListaAlumnos() {
  const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  
  const [alumnos, setAlumnos] = useState([]); 

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAlumnos = async () => {
      try {
        const token = await getAccessTokenSilently({
          audience: "localhost:8080/seguridad",
        });
        console.log("token " + token);

        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/alumno", {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        setAlumnos(data); 
      } catch (error) {
        alert("error");
      }
    };

    fetchAlumnos();
  }, [getAccessTokenSilently]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Aquí estará la lista de alumnos</h1>
      {alumnos.map((alumno) => (
        <div key={alumno.id}>{alumno.nombre}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

this is my function, when I enter here with my first login, I get the error alert

the problem is getAccessTokenSilently. in my console it appears: Error: External interaction required.
Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer, although I hate it, is to ignore it. This error you're getting is occurring via the silent authentication process. In your case, that "process" is when `getAccessTokenSilently` is invoked.

What's happening is that there is a token in your cache that is invalid. When the `getAccessTokenSilenty` runs, it tries to use the current token to authenticate. If that token has expired or become invalid, an exception is thrown that ultimately just means the user needs to log in.

The answer is to only run `getAccessTokenSilently` if the user is *actually* authenticated. Auth0 has an available observable called `isAuthenticated$` that handles some other this logic for you. However, `isAuthenticated$` only checks for the existence of a token and doesn't care about it's validity.

In my case, I use `isAuthenticated$` along with checking the token expiration before running `getAccessTokenSilently`.

Comment: The login is for the first time.  no caching involved as the user has used it for the first time.  isAuthentication is not a valid solution here. Is it got to do something with the actions?

Comment: I did run into some scenario in the auth0 community threads that put the blame on any actions that might be doing a redirect in the auth flow. Might try commenting out/disabling any actions you have to see if the error goes away. But, what's described in this answer was what's happening in my case. could very well be an xy problem with the action in place though.